WHERE condition using dateTime fields not working properly
I am using the Bulk API and when I run a query with a condition
WHERE LastModifiedDate > 2024-04-13T00:00:01.000Z it returns around 1000 records. But when I run another query, with WHERE CreatedDate > 2024-04-13T00:00:01.000Z, it returns a lot more records, majority of which has LastModifiedDate > 2024-04-13T00:00:01.000Z. What am I doing wrong?

Are you sure that there are no typos in query? Normally created date always <= last modified date

According to the documentation the supported formats for date/time values do not include fractions of a second. If you remove the ".000Z" and replace with just "Z", does the query work better?

Sure there are no typos, when I use REST API query SELECT+COUNT(Id)+FROM+xxx+WHERE+CreatedDate+%3E+2024-04-13T00:00:01.000Z returns around 70k records, as it should, but when i use it in BULK API i can only see around a 1000

What are you trying to achieve? Try writing in plain English the description of the records you want to fetch with your query. It might give you (and others) a better idea of what is going on.

Is bulk API returning data in chunks here?

I don't exactly now why, but limiting the number of records that are being returned (by adding LIMIT 100000000000000 to the query) fixed my issue.
